# Reshape dataframe to have columns as rows in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with the following format :

```
ClientID     Group   CountC   
  X1           A       3
  R3           B       2
  D4           A       1
  T5           A       7
  H0           B       5
```

I wanted to calculate the quartiles of `CountC` and store the values in another dataframe, I did the following code:

```
calculate_quantile <- function(data, proba) { 
  z <- quantile(data, proba)
  df <- data.frame(Proba = proba, Value = z)
  return(df)
}

proba = c(0.25, 0.50, 0.75)

quartileDF <- calculate_quantile(df$CountC, proba)
```

Result in `quartileDF` is in the following format:

```
        Proba    Value
25%      0.25      1
50%      0.50      3
75%      0.75      7
```

What I need to do now is calculate the same thing but **by group**.

I tried the following function:

```
q = c(.25, .5, .75)

quartileDFbyGroup <- 
  df%>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
      summarize(quant25 = quantile(df$CountC, probs = q[1]), 
              quant50 = quantile(df$CountC, probs = q[2]),
              quant75 = quantile(df$CountC, probs = q[3]))
```

It gave me the following result :

```
Group     quant25  quant50   quant75
  A         1         2        5
  B         1         3        7
```

But I want the result to be stocked in a dataframe **with the following format ideally**:

```
        Proba    Value    Group
25%      0.25      1        A
50%      0.50      2        A
75%      0.75      5        A 
25%      0.25      1        B
50%      0.50      3        B
75%      0.75      7        B
```

Any idea of how I can stock the results in the format above instead?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
res=aggregate(CountC~Group,df,quantile,c(0.25,0.5,0.75))

  Group CountC.25% CountC.50% CountC.75%
1     A       2.00       3.00       5.00
2     B       2.75       3.50       4.25
```

for your ideal format

```
library(reshape2)    
res2=melt(res$CountC)
res2["Var1"]=res$Group

  Var1 Var2 value
1    A  25%  2.00
2    B  25%  2.75
3    A  50%  3.00
4    B  50%  3.50
5    A  75%  5.00
6    B  75%  4.25
```

**Edit:** another option using only base functions

```
res2=data.frame(lapply(split(df$CountC,df$Group),quantile,c(0.25,0.5,0.75)))
cbind("prb"=rownames(res2),stack(res2))

  prb values ind
1 25%   2.00   A
2 50%   3.00   A
3 75%   5.00   A
4 25%   2.75   B
5 50%   3.50   B
6 75%   4.25   B
```

Answer (score 0):

A pivot_longer can maybe help you with the quartileDFbyGroup table you have at the end.

Try this :

```
df_long <- pivot_longer(quartileDFbyGroup ,
                        cols = c(2,3,4),
                        names_to = "name",
                        values_to = "value")
```

Comment: Hello, this works, thanks. However, do you know a way I can create the table in this format directly to avoid importing multiple libraries and doing a lot of manipulation on the tables ?

Comment: Maybe from your first function that seem to give you what you want, you should iterate it for each group. By creating a list of data.frames, where the data.frames will be the result of each group. Then you output the data.frames of the list to join them into a single one with something like: data.frame(matrix(unlist(list_result)))